# How to get 3 values after a decimal point without converting it to a string in C#(Original value is double)

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to get the decimal value from a double value.

For example:

> 23.56 -> 23.560

Comment: It's the same value. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: If you're not converting it to a string, what *are* you doing with it?  In what way do you believe these values are different or would be in any way stored differently?

Comment: Get a decimal value from a double value? Are we talking about casting here?

Comment: You can cast from double to decimal using `decimal decVal = (decimal) someDoubleValue;` ... For rounding of, you can use `Decimal.Round(decVal, numberOfDecimalPlaces)`

Comment: The purpose is this value are the sales of the product in oman they use three digits after the decimal point that's why I asked here. Can any one help?

Comment: @MohamedSafras: This sounds like what's called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  "They use three digits after the decimal point" isn't a problem, it's just a vague statement.  In your code, what is the specific problem that you've encountered?  Where are "three digits" required and in what specific way does it fail when you provide the value `23.56`?

Comment: 1. Do _not_ use double for _any_ monetary amounts. 2. 2 or 3 (or none, for that matter) is only a question of display. So you want to round and convert to string in the last step, only.

Answer (score 1):

Neither numeric type can store the value 23.560 in exactly this way.

Comment: @MohamedSafras The trailing "0" is purely for display. "23.56" and "23.560" will have the exact same binary representation.

Comment: @MohamedSafras cannot be more clear. For any type 23.560 = 23.56, so it will be stored as 23.56

Comment: @MohamedSafras By the way, to use Double for money calculations is very bad.